# Sending log emails with monolog

Tags: php, email, logging, monolog

I'm so lost right now. I'm trying to send an email of my logs via Amazon SES. I got that working, but I can't figure out how to send the log data?!

Now I'm trying to take a few steps back and just send the email via monolog's SwiftMailerHandler, as I thought I might be able to figure out how they're converting the log files, but I can't even figure this out.

How am I supposed to use the protected "send" method in this [class](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/SwiftMailerHandler.php)

Comment: Pass in a switftmailer instance to the constructor and it should send logs with the set level or higher automagically

Comment: I have tried that. Is there a way to just convert logs to a string?